# Remove linux-image-4.10.0-27-generic

Tags: 16.04

I try to run  this command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

But every time I get this:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-4.10.0-27-generic* linux-image-extra-4.10.0-27-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 2067 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 226 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 394532 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.10.0-27-generic (4.10.0-27.30~16.04.2) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.10.0-27-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-27-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.10.0-27-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-27-generic
```

And stuck at the end , if I want to do something else I must kill this process. I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Any idea how to solve it??

Edit:
The command

```
dkms status -k 4.10.0-27-generic
```

Give:

```
virtualbox, 5.0.40, 4.10.0-27-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: are you using that kernel? to remove a kernel properly, you need to be booted on a different kernel.

Comment: To find out if you are running that kernel, enter the command `uname -r`

Comment: I use this one 4.10.0-35-generic

Comment: Any suggestion???

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `dkms status -k 4.10.0-27-generic`? Thanks.

Comment: It may also help to see the output of `pstree -alU | sed -ne '/[─\/ ]apt-get/,/└/p'` while `apt-get upgrade` has been stuck for 5 minutes or so.